# Como comparar o horário atual com outro digitado pelo usuário?

Tags: python, data, datetime

Preciso escrever um código que leia uma hora qualquer inserida pelo usuário. (Formato Exemplo: 09:25) e imprima na tela se a hora digitada pelo usuário é maior ou menor do que a hora atual.

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, timezone

fuso_brasil = timezone(timedelta(hours=-3))

hora_atual = datetime.now().time()

hora_inserida_pelo_usuario = input('Digite uma hora: ')

if hora_inserida_pelo_usuario > hora_atual:
    print('A hora fornecida pelo usuario é MAIOR')

else:
    print('A hora fornecida pelo usuario é MENOR')
```

Porém ocorre o erro:

> ```
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.time'
> ```

Comment: Esta  comparando a string `hora_inserida_pelo_usuario` com um objeto que é um time, pode ser corrigido usando [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.fromisoformat)  ou  [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)  tera que converter essa entrada  `hora_inserida_pelo_usuario` usando um desses.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Esse código funciona se você der uma entrada com horas:minutos exemplo 09:45 mas não funcionaria se você passasse os segundos, então não é a melhor solução mas funciona no cenário passado no seu exemplo

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, timezone

fuso_brasil = timezone(timedelta(hours=-3))

hora_atual = str(datetime.now().time()).split(".")[0] #retiro os milesimos
hora_atual = hora_atual.split(":") #separo a string pelos ":"
hora_atual = int (hora_atual[0]+hora_atual[1]) #pego somente as horas e minutos e transformo em int

hora_inserida_pelo_usuario = int (input('Digite uma hora: ').replace(":","")) #retiro os ":" e transformo em um numero só

if hora_inserida_pelo_usuario > hora_atual:
    print('A hora fornecida pelo usuario é MAIOR')

else:
    print('A hora fornecida pelo usuario é MENOR')
```

Comment: Estranho que mesmo com o seu exemplo continua dando erro.

Digite uma hora: 12:55
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thiago\PycharmProjects\Compara_Hora\Compara_Hora.py", line 9, in <module>
    if hora_inserida_pelo_usuario > hora_atual:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.time'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Estranho... você pode mostrar como ficou seu arquivo?

Comment: O mesmo erro do usuário que postou a pergunta original: **qualquer comparação  entre uma string e  um tipo  datetime.time**   não é **POSSIVEL**

Comment: seria possível transformar o valor recebido no datetime para um numero inteiro e depois simplesmente fazer a comparação de qual é maior? 

Teria também que remover o : para ficar um numero só

Comment: Estava executando o arquivo errado, deu certo. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda =]

Answer (score 1):

Apesar da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/575931/112052) ter "funcionado", está **muito** longe de ser o ideal. Você está usando o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), e ele já possui todas as ferramentas necessárias para o que pretende fazer. Não precisa ficar manipulando a string manualmente, é uma gambiarra completamente desnecessária.

Enfim, o problema do seu código é que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string, mas a sua `hora_atual` é um objeto do [tipo `time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects), e eles não podem ser comparados diretamente. Para isso você precisa transformar a string em `time`.

Se o usuário vai digitar o horário no formato "HH:MM", basta usar o [método `time.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.fromisoformat). Ele não só é mais flexível (aceita "HH:MM", "HH:MM:SS" e até frações de segundo: "HH:MM:SS.sss"), como também já faz as devidas validações.

Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar "35:99" ou "12345:395454", `time.fromisoformat` vai lançar uma exceção, por ser um horário inválido - já o código da outra resposta vai aceitar quaisquer números que vierem, mesmo que não sejam um horário válido (em exercícios talvez não seja um problema, mas em código sério rodando em produção, aí passa a ser). **Essa é uma das grandes vantagens de usar as funções prontas do módulo, em vez de fazer tudo manualmente**. Só porque o outro código "funcionou", não quer dizer que seja o mais correto a se fazer.

No seu caso, bastaria fazer:

```py
from datetime import datetime, time

hora_atual = datetime.now().time()

hora_inserida_pelo_usuario = time.fromisoformat(input('Digite uma hora: '))

if hora_inserida_pelo_usuario > hora_atual:
    # etc
```

Ou, se quiser validar e pedir para digitar novamente em caso de horário inválido:

```py
while True:
    try:
        hora_inserida_pelo_usuario = time.fromisoformat(input('Digite uma hora: '))
        break # deu certo, sai do while
    except ValueError as erro: # se digitar horário inválido
        print(erro) # opção: imprimir o erro
        # Ou mostrar uma mensagem genérica
        print("Digite um horário válido")

if hora_inserida_pelo_usuario > hora_atual:
    # etc
```

O detalhe é que, como já dito, `fromisoformat` aceita vários formatos ("HH:MM", "HH:MM:SS", "HH:MM:SS.sss", etc). Mas se quiser ser mais restrito (por exemplo, aceitar apenas "HH:MM"), aí tem que usar [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```py
# aceita apenas HH:MM
# (e também pode colocar dentro do while acima, se quiser que o usuário
#  digite novamente em caso de horário inválido)
hora_inserida_pelo_usuario = datetime.strptime(input('Digite uma hora: '), '%H:%M').time()
```

Assim, ele vai aceitar somente o formato "HH:MM". Se digitar qualquer formato diferente (como "HH:MM:SS", por exemplo), será considerado inválido.

---

Outro detalhe é que você considera que se o horário digitado não é maior, então necessariamente é menor. Mas isso não é verdade, porque eles podem ser iguais, então poderia ser assim:

```py
if hora_inserida_pelo_usuario > hora_atual:
    print('A hora fornecida pelo usuario é MAIOR')
elif hora_inserida_pelo_usuario < hora_atual:
    print('A hora fornecida pelo usuario é MENOR')
else:
    print('Os horários são iguais')
```

Enfim, detalhes... :-)

---

Outra coisa: `datetime.now()` retorna o horário atual, **incluindo os segundos e as frações de segundo**. Mas se a ideia é comparar somente hora e minuto, então você teria que zerá-los no horário atual:

```py
# zera os segundos e as frações de segundo
hora_atual = datetime.now().time().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

# o resto é igual
```

Como você quer que o usuário digite somente hora e minuto, então pode ser que você queira ignorar os segundos na comparação (pois tanto `isofromformat` quanto `strptime` setam os segundos para zero caso eles não sejam fornecidos). Aí faria sentido usar o código acima.

---

## Fuso horário

Você criou o `fuso_brasil`, mas acabou não usando.

Se quer o fuso horário brasileiro, primeiro precisa lembrar que [o Brasil tem vários fusos horários](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil), então usar um valor fixo como `-3` está longe de ser o ideal. Tem regiões que são `-4`, `-5` ou `-2`. Sem contar que existe também o horário de verão, quando esse valor muda (por exemplo, em São Paulo muda de `-3` para `-2`).

Em vez de usar um valor fixo, o ideal é usar os [timezones da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), que são identificadores como `America/Sao_Paulo`, que já tratam desses casos para você (ele sabe quando o *offset* é `-3` ou `-2`, por exemplo). Claro que mesmo assim você terá que escolher **qual região do Brasil** você vai considerar ([e são várias](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2022g/zone.tab#L89)). Por exemplo, hoje São Paulo e Recife possuem o mesmo *offset* (`-3`, ou seja, 3 horas atrás do UTC). Mas houve momentos em que São Paulo teve horário de verão e Recife não (um mudou para `-2`, o outro permaneceu em `-3`), e por isso são considerados timezones diferentes: respectivamente, `America/Sao_Paulo` e `America/Recife`. Escolher o identificador errado pode dar diferença, dependendo do que você precisa.

Enfim, uma vez escolhido o timezone, basta usá-lo para obter a data/hora atual. Infelizmente a classe `timezone` do módulo `datetime` não serve para isso (a própria [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) diz isso: "*cannot be used to represent timezone information in the locations where different offsets are used in different days of the year or where historical changes have been made to civil time*"), então temos duas opções:

- Até o Python 3.8, você pode instalar o [módulo `pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) (`pip install pytz`)
- A partir do Python 3.9, a linguagem já vem com o [módulo `zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo)

Exemplo:

```py
# obter o horário atual em um timezone específico

from datetime import datetime

# Até Python 3.8, use o módulo pytz (instalar com "pip install pytz")
# https://pypi.org/project/pytz/
from pytz import timezone

fuso_brasil = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
hora_atual = datetime.now(fuso_brasil).time()

##################################
# A partir do Python 3.9 não precisa instalar nada, o módulo zoneinfo já vem com a linguagem
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

fuso_brasil = ZoneInfo('America/Sao_Paulo')
hora_atual = datetime.now(fuso_brasil).time()
```

Outra vantagem é que se algo mudar (por exemplo, hoje não tem horário de verão no Brasil, mas pode ser que volte no futuro), basta atualizar essas informações: o `pytz` sempre lança uma nova versão sincronizada com a IANA, e o módulo `zoneinfo` usa as informações do sistema (bastando portanto mantê-las atualizadas), mas caso não esteja disponível, ele lê do [módulo `tzdata`](https://tzdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (basta instalar e manter atualizado). Mas independente de qual esteja usando, de forma geral o código não precisaria mudar, bastando atualizar as informações dos timezones.